# How to find out, what a song playing now in my playlist with use SoundCloud API?

Tags: api, soundcloud

Good day. I use SoundCloud and I want get a song name which playing now. I can use JS or PHP for this. Please help me for find correct example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When your track starts playing (listen for the [`SC.Widget.Events.PLAY`](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#events) event), you can use the `getCurrentSound` method.

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('#player');
var sc = SC.Widget(iframe);

// ...

sc.getCurrentSound(function(music){
        console.log(music.title);
});
```

`getCurrentSound` returns a `sound` object, which has a [title](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) property.

Relevant documentation [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#methods).